# When was the term "Liedermacher" introduced?

Tags: etymology

When was the term Liedermacher first used in German?

It seemed to have been used in the 70s, but I wonder whether it was coined in that time or is much older?

Comment: The term (perhaps in another context, though), appears already in Julius Stinde's novel, which precisely is entitled *Der Liedermacher*.

Comment: Kommt auch schon in Grimm's Wörterbuch vor, damit in den 1860ern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Abhandlung "Mani Matter und die Liedermacher" von Stephan Hammer enthält einen [Überblick über die Geschichte des Begriffs](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZIinCp8rR4oC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=urheberschaft+der+bezeichnung+liedermacher&source=bl&ots=sVi_31sRZH&sig=mw4ED1V_WrmdQ0p0vMXkQeNF66Y&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimjpPE0JXTAhXHcRQKHeLfB8MQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=urheberschaft%20der%20bezeichnung%20liedermacher&f=false):

Laut eigenen Angaben habe Wolf Biermann diesen Begriff 1961 geformt. Ein erster Textbeleg findet sich in einem Zeitungsartikel von Dezember 1964. Es gab allerdings schon weit früher Verwendungen des Begriffs, der älteste Beleg stammt aus dem Jahr 1757.

Den Verweis auf Biermann findet man auch andernorts, u.a. bei [wissen-digital.de](http://www.wissen-digital.de/Wolf_Biermann). Demzufolge hat ihn Biermann in Anlehnung an Brechts "Stückeschreiber" geformt (oder eben wiederbelebt). Dieses [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Liedermacher&year_start=1600&year_end=2017&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLiedermacher%3B%2Cc0) zeigt, wie der Begriff seit Anfang der 1960er Jahre rasant populär wurde, aber eben auch schon weit vorher verwendet wurde.